# How to get most repeated string array in Pymongo?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

How can I get most repeated value for gender and age respectively?
My data:

```
[{  "_id": ObjectId("5dff27c0ac2d1547d87a1fe7"), "time": "2019-12-20 21:09:53",        
        "object": [{"Id": 1,"gender": "female","age": "0-10"},
                    {"Id": 2,"gender": "female","age": "20-30"}]
},
{   "_id": ObjectId("5dff27c0ac2d1547d87a1fe8"), "time": "2019-12-20 21:09:53",        
        "object": [{"Id": 1,"gender": "male","age": "0-10"},
                    {"Id": 2,"gender": "female","age": "30-40"}]
} , 
{   "_id": ObjectId("5dff27c0ac2d1547d87a1fe9"), "time": "2019-12-20 21:09:53",        
        "object": [{"Id": 1,"gender": "male","age": "10-15"},
                    {"Id": 2,"gender": "female","age": "30-40"},
                    {"Id": 3,"gender": "male","age": "0-10"}]
},
{   "_id": ObjectId("5dff27c0ac2d1547d87a1fea"), "time": "2019-12-20 21:09:53",        
        "object": [{"Id": 2,"gender": "male","age": "40-50"},
                    {"Id": 3,"gender": "male","age": "0-10"},
                    {"Id": 4,"gender": "male","age": "0-10"}]
}]
```

I have written below query,

```
mongo.db.xyz.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$object"},
    {"$group" : {"_id" : "$object.Id","_gen":{"$push":"$object.gender"},"_age":{"$push":"$object.age"}}},
    { "$project": { "_id" : "$_id", "gender":"$_gen","age":"$_age"}}
    ])
```

Below is the result I am getting,

```
[{"_id": 3,"age": ["0-10","0-10"],"gender": ["male","male"]},
 {"_id": 2,"age": ["20-30","30-40","30-40","40-50"],"gender": ["female","female","female","male"]},
 {"_id": 4,"age": ["0-10"],"gender": ["male"]},
 {"_id": 1,"age": ["0-10","0-10","10-15"],"gender": ["female","male","male"]}
]
```

But I want the output to be ,

```
[{"_id": 3,"age": "0-10","gender": "male"},
 {"_id": 2,"age": "30-40","gender": "female"},
 {"_id": 4,"age": "0-10","gender": "male"},
 {"_id": 1,"age": "0-10","gender": "male"}
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample data of your collection?

Comment: @AliHusseinat Please check my updated question

Comment: If I got the expected result right, what you want is the most repeated pair "gender" and "age" in the array of each object. Is that correct?

Comment: I suggest you to always make your questions as clear as possible so you will get answers faster :)

Comment: For each object.Id I want to get mode of gender and mode of age. For example. For example, In object.Id 1 , gender = [female,male,male] , so the mode of gender would be 'male', and age = [0-10,0-10,10-15] , here the mode of age is '0-15'. Similarly I want modes of gender and modes of age for each objectid

Comment: Please, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this problem I realized it was not so simple to get the mode of some fields independently in an array of objects with just one db query. To solve that I created a query to do it generically, based on your sample data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$arr"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      arr: {
        $objectToArray: "$arr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$arr"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        k: "$arr.k",
        v: "$arr.v"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      count: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id._id",
        k: "$_id.k"
      },
      v: {
        $first: "$_id.v"
      },
      count: {
        $first: "$count"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id._id"
      },
      arr: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.k",
          v: {
            mode: "$v",
            count: "$count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      arr: {
        $arrayToObject: "$arr"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The secret to do that is to use the $objectToArray and the $arrayToObject operations, along with the $unwind and the correct $group stages. If you need a more detailed response on any stage please ask in the comments.

The output of the sample data is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5dff27c0ac2d1547d87a1fea")
    },
    "arr": {
      "Id": {
        "count": 1,
        "mode": 3
      },
      "age": {
        "count": 2,
        "mode": "0-10"
      },
      "gender": {
        "count": 3,
        "mode": "male"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5dff27c0ac2d1547d87a1fe7")
    },
    "arr": {
      "Id": {
        "count": 1,
        "mode": 2
      },
      "age": {
        "count": 1,
        "mode": "0-10"
      },
      "gender": {
        "count": 2,
        "mode": "female"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5dff27c0ac2d1547d87a1fe9")
    },
    "arr": {
      "Id": {
        "count": 1,
        "mode": 2
      },
      "age": {
        "count": 1,
        "mode": "30-40"
      },
      "gender": {
        "count": 2,
        "mode": "male"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5dff27c0ac2d1547d87a1fe8")
    },
    "arr": {
      "Id": {
        "count": 1,
        "mode": 2
      },
      "age": {
        "count": 1,
        "mode": "30-40"
      },
      "gender": {
        "count": 1,
        "mode": "female"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

After running it for a collection that has an array of objects named "arr" (**edit the query if in your collection it has a different name**) it will return the mode value and the number of occurrences of that value for each field. Objects that has that field unset will be not considered, but the ones with "null" will.